# Integral representation of volume via orthogonal projections

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, convex-geometry

I'm reading a book, and the author consider the following situation: Let $K$ be a compact, convex set with nonempty interior in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, given any $m$-dimensional subspace $F$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, an application of Fubini's theorem yields

$$
\text{vol}_n(K) = \int_{P_{F^{\perp}}(K)} \text{vol}_m(K \cap (x + F)) dx,
$$
where $P_{F^{\perp}}(K)$ denotes the orthogonal projection of $K$ onto the orthogonal complement $F^{\perp}$ of $F$, where $\text{vol}_m$ denotes the $m$-dimensional volume.

I really don't understand how the author got this identity by applying Fubini's theorem. Does anyone have any idea how this might work?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you copied the formula correctly?  It should reduce to formulas from elementary calculus for calculating volumes by slicing.

Comment: Sorry, no, that other $K$ should be an $F$. Adjusting it now.

Comment: And now that I've written the $F$ and drew the picture, I see how it shows up. I'm sorry for that!

Comment: Good, you figured it out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The volume of $K$ can be written as the integral of the volumes/areas of $m$-dimensional cross-sections. Each cross-section $K \cap (x + F)$ can be indexed by an element $x \in P_{F^\perp}(K)$, as $x$ describes how far you need to slide the subspace $F$ to obtain the slice of $K$ that you want.

It may help to try examples with $n=2$ and $m=1$ (or $n=3$ and $m =2$) for intuition.

Comment: Thank you. I drew a picture and immediately realized how it should look; I misread the book :/